# Поиск текста в словнике Dictionary

Tags: c#, поиск, словари

Программа распределения вещей в рюкзаке.
На пикчербокче я ставлю метки (у каждой метки свои координаты) - типа карман. При клике на метку открывается новая форма, где есть ТекстБокс (Содержание кармана). 
[image: Программа]

После его заполнения, мы закрываем форму и сохраняем все с помощью словаря `Dictionary`:

```
  private Dictionary<Point, Dictionary<String, String>> dict = new Dictionary<Point, Dictionary<String, String>>();  // *словарь из координатами точек и записями в них*
```

Сохраняется все в файле.txt так:

```
C:\Users\yuretz\Desktop\!kursach - копия\img\1.jpg
{"294, 251":{"comment":"Спички\r\nРубашка\r\n"},"142, 260":{"comment":"Вилка\r\nЛожка"}}
```

**Задание**: реализовать поиск вещей по карманам. По сути мне просто нужно добраться до значения Value во внутреннем словаре.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Как мне записать в коде, что бы после поиска я выводил сообщение, на экран ? Нужно что то типо 
If (result)  
MessageBox.Show("Есть совпадения!");
else
MessageBox.Show("Совпадений нету!");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так (если я не запутался в ваших словарях):

```
string thing = @"Спички";
var result = dict.Where(
    n => n.Value.Any(
         m => m.Value.Split(new char[] {'\r','\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(
             t => t.ToLower() == thing.ToLower())));
```

UPD к вашему коментарию:

```
if (result.Count() > 0) { 
    MessageBox.Show("Есть совпадения!"); }
else { 
    MessageBox.Show("Совпадений нету!"); }
```